# Attempting to fill a table with the number of elements in each bin and make a table with the elements in the bins?

Tags: list-manipulation, data, gathering

I am having some difficulty trying to fill a table with the number of elements in each bin while also making a table that holds the elements in each bin.

Okay, let me go over my thoughts:

So I have a list:

```
dat = {0,1,3,9,11,13,14,15,19,20};
```

I want to have each bin be a constant width, which I have set at 5, so I know to find the number of bins:

```
numBins = (Max[dat] - Min[dat])/width
```

To get my intervals, I wrote:

```
intervals = Table[0,2*numBins];
intervals[[1]] = min;
For[i = 2, i < 2*numBins, i+=2, intervals[[i]] = intervals[[i-1]] + width; intervals[[i+1]] = intervals[[i]]] 
intervals[[2*numBins]] = intervals[[2*numBins - 1]] + width;
```

which gets me:

```
{0, 5, 5, 10, 10, 15, 15, 20}
```

which is exactly what I'm looking for. Now, I know that for the bins, I should get:

```
0-5, 5-10, 10-15, 15-20 (intervals)

0    9     11     19    (elements in bins)
1          13     20
3          14        
           15

3    1     4      2     (number of elements in each bin)
```

Now, I thought that to get the number of elements in each bin and fill in a bin table, I might do something like (pseudocode-ish)

```
int k = 0;
numOfElements = Table[0, {i,numBins}]
elements = Table[0, {i, numBins}, {j, Length[dat]}]
for(int i = 2, i < Length[intervals], i+=2){
for(int j = 0, j < Length[dat], j++){
if(dat[[j]] > intervals[[i]] && dat[[j]] < intervals[[i+1]]){
elements[[i]][[j]] = dat[[j]];
count++;
}
numOfElements[[k]] = count;
k++;
count = 0;
}}
```

What I'm having problems with is 1) is this the correct logic? and 2) implementing in Mathematica. Any help in tackling this problem would be greatly appreciated.

**EDIT:** @kglr pointed out a lot of good stuff and I also noticed BinCounts, which is useful, but I noticed that

```
BinLists[dat, 5] /. {}->Nothing
```

gets me

```
{{0, 1, 3}, {9}, {11, 13, 14}, {15, 19}, {20}}
```

when what I'm looking to try to get is

```
{{0, 1, 3}, {9}, {11, 13, 14, 15}, {19, 20}}
```

So while BinLists gets me something close, it's not quite what I'm trying to do.

Comment: see [`BinLists`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/BinLists.html) and [`HistogramList`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/HistogramList.html)?

Comment: @kglr Jeeze, yep, BinLists. Curious though - do you have any advice on how to set and appropriate x_max, because Length[dat] isn't nearly long enough.

Comment: Jomy,  maybe you can do what `BinLists` does:  [Binlists >> Details](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/BinLists.html) : _BinLists[data,dx] takes the bin boundaries to be integer multiples of dx, with the first bin starting at Ceiling[Min[data]-dx,dx] and the last bin ending at Floor[Max[data]+dx,dx]. _

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`BinLists`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/BinLists.html) and [`HistogramList`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/HistogramList.html) as follows:

```
dat = {0, 1, 3, 9, 11, 13, 14, 15, 19, 20};

BinLists[dat, 5]
```

> {{}, {0, 1, 3}, {9}, {11, 13, 14}, {15, 19}, {20}}

```
{binlims, bincounts} = HistogramList[dat, {5}]
```

> {{-5, 0, 5, 10, 15, 20, 25}, {0, 3, 1, 3, 2, 1}}

**Update:** To get `{{0, 1, 3}, {9}, {11, 13, 14, 15}, {19, 20}}` as the result you can specify explicit bin limits (e.g.,`{{0, 5, 10, 16, 20}}` or  `{{0, 5, 10, 15 + .0001 , 20}}`) as the second argument of `BinLists`:

```
BinLists[dat, {{0, 5, 10, 16, 25}}]
```

> {{0, 1, 3}, {9}, {11, 13, 14, 15}, {19, 20}}

Comment: Interesting! Can you explain why BinLists gives this empty {} and why HistogramList gives this -5 and 0 term? Is there a way to get rid of those?

Comment: @JomyBlue, you get `{}` when a bin is empty. In this case the first bin (the interval from -5 to 0) is empty. To get rid of them you replace them with `Nothing`: that is, `BinLists[dat, 5] /. {}->Nothing`

Comment: @JomyBlue Alternatively, you can specify that the first bin should start at the minimum value of the list: `dx = 5; BinLists[dat, {Min[dat], Max[dat] + dx, dx}]` returns `{{0, 1, 3}, {9}, {11, 13, 14}, {15, 19}, {20}}`.

Comment: Thanks for telling me that!

Comment: Huh, I just noticed that this puts 15 in bin 3, when, for my purposes, I want 15 in bin 2.

Comment: I just noticed that HistogramList[dat, {5}] doesn't give me the intervals I'm looking for - it gives {0, 5, 10, 15, 20, 25}, but the intervals I'm using are {0, 5, 10, 15, 20}.

Comment: @JomyBlue, please see the update.

Comment: That's interesting, but only works if you know your bin intervals in advance, right? Since I want to deal with data sets with lengths much larger than 10, this would prove to be cumbersome... Oh, but I suppose if you make the intervals {0, 6, 11, 16, 21} that would work. So generalizing, for the intervals you essentially leave the first interval alone and just add one to the other.

Comment: Wonderful, your comment helped me figure out how to edit my intervals list to get the bins I want. Thank you so much for your help.